# Delete duplicate rows with different index values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe containing product data with product ID stored as the index value and other attributes as the columns. Due to human error, sometimes duplicate entries for the same item occur and I need to filter out these duplicates. Everything is the same for a given duplicate row from the previous row **except** the ProductID (index value).

Is there a way to delete rows that contain the exact same values that are clearly duplicate entries despite having different index values? A sample of what i'm referring to is below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sure, You can use `drop_duplicates()` function from pandas. Look at the below example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    'brand': ['Yum Yum', 'Yum Yum', 'Indomie', 'Indomie', 'Indomie'],
    'style': ['cup', 'cup', 'cup', 'pack', 'pack'],
    'rating': [4, 4, 3.5, 15, 5]})

df.drop_duplicates(subset=['brand', 'style', 'rating'])
```

As you can see, I used `drop_duplicates()` function with parameter `subset=[]` which allows me to set columns, witch, I want to analyze. If you want to read more about this function click [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

To improve the code above you can use

```
subset=df.columns.difference(['id'])
```

instead of

```
subset=df.columns.difference(['id'])
```

It allows to passing name of the column which shouldn't be analyzed, in your case you should use code like this:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=df.columns.difference(['ProductID']))
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `drop_duplicates()`? `duplicated` *identifies* duplicates and `drop_duplicates()` *actually drops them*

Comment: I edited the answer, now it allows to remove duplicated rows.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

```
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
```

The `ignore_index=True` will create a new continuos index ProductIDs (without gaps)